# Kendo MVC grid with editable enum column

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a simple model that I need to display and edit in Kendo's MVC Grid component.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string SomeProperty {get; set;}
    public MyEnum MyEnum {get; set;}
}

public enum MyEnum
{
    FirstItem = 1,
    SecondItem = 2,
    ThirdItem = 3
}
```

And I have my grid set up like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo()
    .Grid<MyModel>()
    .Name("grid").Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.SomeProperty).Width(200);
        columns.Bound(o => o.MyEnum).Width(200);
        columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Edit().Text("Edit");
        }).Width(220);
    })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(false)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.Id);
            model.Field(p => p.SomeProperty);
            model.Field(p => p.MyEnum);

        })
        .Create(...) // removed for confidentiality
        .Read(...)
        .Update(...)
        .Events(...)
    ).Filterable()
  .Sortable())
```

After executing the edit command, I receive updated model in controller's method defined in `Update(...)`.

```
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Update(
        [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,
        MyModel myModel)
```

However no matter what I do, `myModel` in controller has default value of `MyEnum`. Even if I change just `SomeProperty` of item that has `MyEnum` set to `SecondItem`, it will be `FirstItem` in the controller. This was verified by looking at the POST request, so the problem is somewhere in the Grid, not on server.

How to do proper data binding to ensure Kendo sends correct `MyEnum` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.ForeignKey()` on a column instead of binding:

```
@(Html.Kendo()
    .Grid<MyModel>()
    .Name("grid").Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.ForeignKey(o => o.MyEnum, ).EditorTemplateName("GridForeignKey").Width(200);

        // SNIP
```

and then define `GridForeignKey.cshtml` in `Views/Shared/EditorTemplate` like this:

```
@model object

@{
    var selectList = (SelectList)ViewData[ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("") + "_Data"];
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, selectList, "Choose...")
```

This way you get a dropdown in your grid and will get correct values into your controller on POST.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. You should to use EditorTemplate (MyEnum.cshtml in Shared\EditorTemplates folder) for MyEnum property:

```
@model MyEnum

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
   .Name("MyEnum")
   .BindTo(EnumHelper.GetSelectList(Model.GetType()))
   .OptionLabel("Please select MyEnum"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a conflict in your model since your enum object property matches the type. Suggest you rename it something like this and give it a try;

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string SomeProperty {get; set;}
    public MyEnum EnumProperty {get; set;}
}
```