# How set editor for column bound to enum in Kendo Grid .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kendo-grid

I have a grid which has a column bound to an enum. It is displayed correctly but when I want to edit the value it is only possible to enter the integers representing the enum. I found multiple solutions to set a editor with a dropdown for ASP .NET but not for ASP .NET Core for example this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31402262/3187001

Which seems to be the way to go to handle this but I did not found any solution working with ASP .NET Core.

My view:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
}
@(
    Html.Kendo().Grid<WebApp.Models.TestModel>
    ()
    .Name("TestGrid").Height(550).Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Save();
    })
    .Columns(cols =>
    {
        cols.Bound(col => col.Name);
        cols.Bound(col => col.Number);
        cols.Bound(col => col.State);
    })
    .Sortable().Scrollable().DataSource(ds => ds
    .Ajax().Batch(true).Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(tpn => tpn.Name);
        model.Field(tpn => tpn.Name).Editable(false);
        model.Field(tpn => tpn.Number);
        model.Field(tpn => tpn.State);
    }
    )
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateTestModels", "Test"))
    .Read(read => read.Action("ReadTestModels", "Test")
    )
    )
    )
```

My controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Test");
        }

        public IActionResult ReadTestModels([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var models = new List<TestModel>();
            models.Add(new TestModel() { Name = "Model 1", Number = 1, State = TestModelState.StateA });
            models.Add(new TestModel() { Name = "Model 2", Number = 1337, State = TestModelState.StateB });
            models.Add(new TestModel() { Name = "Model 3", Number = 42, State = TestModelState.StateC });

            return Json(models.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }

        [AcceptVerbs("Post")]
        public IActionResult UpdateTestModels([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,
        [Bind(Prefix = "models")] IEnumerable<TestModel> testModels)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{testModels.Count()} Testmodels updated...");
            return Json(testModels.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
public class TestModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public TestModelState State { get; set; }
    }

public enum TestModelState
    {
        Undefined = 0,
        StateA = 1,
        StateB = 2,
        StateC = 3
    }
```